# How to make "buffered output" in R disabled by default?

Tags: r

When I work on the R console, I always want my results to be displayed instantly rather than buffered. Is there any method to turn buffered output off by default, so I don't need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> every time I start the R console?

It definitely doesn't look like I'm the first one who encounters this, but surprisingly I can find nothing on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in your R directory under `etc`, you should find a file called `Rconsole`, which contains a number of options that govern the behavior of the console. One of them is `buffered = yes`. Change `yes` to `no` and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks! However I found that the correct directory to look for the `Rconsole` file is at `Sys.getenv("R_USER")`. Wish I had asked this earlier!

Is there any particular reason why it is enabled by default? To me there isn't any situation in which I prefer to have buffering on.

Comment: @David I believe it is time- and/or memory-saving when trying to print a very large object (e.g., a 1 million observation data.frame), but I actually do not know for sure.